# zip function for Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

Is there some standard API or established third party library (I am thinking commons or Guava) that provides in Java the equivalent of `zip` or `map vector` function in languages like Ruby or Clojure?

```
(zip '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
'( (1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```

So the signature (for two collections) would be:

```
public static <V,T> List< Pair<V, T> > zip (List<V> vs, List<T> ts);
```

where `Pair` would also be presumably defined in that library. I know its trivial to implement but maybe said library has other functional goodies too.

Comment: Guava is against Pair in the first place.  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard per se.  I've played with [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) a bit, and it's ok for basic stuff.

This was answered in more detail here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101352/is-functional-programming-possible-in-java#101361

But you could also consider using something like [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) (which runs on the JVM)

Answer (score 2):

[FunctionalJava](http://functionaljava.org/) has a `zip` implementation

Comment: Yeap, should have mentioned that - I came across that but it didn't seem very established (e.g. no ivy deps in maven repo)

Answer (score 0):

Guava has a [Streams.zip](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.function.BiFunction)) function and Apache commons has a [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) class. Here is some example code using both to do this

```
import com.google.common.collect.Streams;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = List.of("a", "b", "c");
        List<Integer> list2 = List.of(1, 2, 3);

        List<Pair<String, Integer>> zipped = Streams.zip(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), Pair::of)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(zipped);
    }
}
```

It prints

```
[(a,1), (b,2), (c,3)]
```